# Adding a new field to page using mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am a bit of a newby to mySQL. I have added a new column that stores image names for images stored in a file (eg.toweltest.jpg). I want to draw these to display images on a page. This is someone else's code I am adapting so its a bit patchy. Basically I want to draw the folder name and then add whatever image name is associated with that product. So far I have this:

```
<?php
$SNIPPET = true;

require './includes/php/header.php';

$product = Product::Get($_GET['product_id']);
$supplier = Supplier::Get($product->supplier_id);
$url = "/products/";
$image = 'toweltest.jpg';
?>

<h1><?php echo htmlspecialchars($product->code); ?><br><br><?php echo htmlspecialchars($product->name); ?></h1>
<h2><?php echo htmlspecialchars($product->description); ?></h2>
<img src='<?php echo $url.$image; ?>'>
```

This shows the image but obviously I want the image that is associated with each product. The part that says:

```
$image = 'toweltest.jpg';
```

needs to be dynamic but I don't know how to phrase it. Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Rich

Comment: which field is that image bound to? I ask because it is not clear from your question. Also you probably might want to use one [`Super::$tatic`](http://i.imgur.com/RJEsz.png) to store your database instead of the many different statics you have there.

Comment: The field is called 'image'. Please see my comments below. I can't comment on the previous code as this was not my project (and I don't want to break anything)... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't tell if we don't know the column name for the image, but it should be something like:

```
$image = $product->image;
```

This is actually a guess, since I can't see the rest of the code.

Comment: sorry, yes I've called the column 'image'. The database code is called by the header. I tried your suggestion before but nothing showed up. Could I have the database column setup wrong?

Comment: and I have set up the column as field=image type=varchar(255) and a sample entry is toweltest.jpg

Comment: Then the problem should be on the Get function for the class Product. It should be included somewhere on your php code, try searching for "class Product" and search for "function Get" inside the class.

Comment: thank you thank you, hopefully there will be no issues, it's quite a complicated system for me. I'm new to stack overflow, how can I big you up Ana?

Comment: No problem, glad it helped, you already rewarded me :) I'm new too haha.